# null subjectline giving null pointer exception

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

With the below code i'm trying to get only the emails that matches the subject line.

```
String subject = "test email";
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    try {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(host, userName, password);
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        int count = inbox.getMessageCount();
        System.out.println(count + " total messages");
        Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            if (messages[i].getSubject().contains(subject)) {
                System.out.println(messages[i].getSubject() + "\t"
                        + messages[i].getSentDate());
            } else {
                System.out.println("subject mismatch");
            }
        }
```

here i'm getting the required result, but the problem kicks when there is a email with no subject line.

I tried the below.

```
else if (messages[i].getSubject().contains(null)) {
                    System.out.println(messages[i].getSubject() + "\t"
                            + messages[i].getSentDate());
                }


else if (messages[i].getSubject().contains("")) {
                    System.out.println(messages[i].getSubject() + "\t"
                            + messages[i].getSentDate());
                }


else if (messages[i].getSubject().contains(" ")) {
                    System.out.println(messages[i].getSubject() + "\t"
                            + messages[i].getSentDate());
                }
```

but still i get the below error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.getEmails.readEmails.main(readEmails.java:34)
```

also instead of `contains`, i tried `equals` and `equalsIgnoreCase`, but still the issue is same.

when printing just subject line without the condition, it was showing `null` as subject line. So i tried the below.

```
else if (messages[i].getSubject().contains("null")) {
                        System.out.println(messages[i].getSubject() + "\t"
                                + messages[i].getSentDate());
                    }
```

but still the error is same.

please let me know how can i fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that whatever the `getSubject()` yields can sometimes be `null`, thus any operations on that will yield a `NullPointerException`, regardless of what type of check you do.

To go around this problem you will need to make a *null check*, something like so:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            if ((messages[i].getSubject() != null) && (messages[i].getSubject().contains(subject))) {
                System.out.println(messages[i].getSubject() + "\t"
                        + messages[i].getSentDate());
            } else {
                System.out.println("subject mismatch");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check for `null` first as it will give `NullPointerException` if  `messages[i]` OR `messages[i].getSubject()` is `null`. Apart from that `contains(null)` has no meaning and must cause `NullPointerException` but `messages[i].getSubject() ==  null` does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
messages[i] != null && messages[i].getSubject() != null && messages[i].getSubject().contains(subject)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what everyone else said, you might want to look into using the [Folder.search](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#search-javax.mail.search.SearchTerm-) method with a [SubjectTerm](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/SubjectTerm.html), which will allow the searching to be done on the server:

```
Message[] messages = inbox.search(new SubjectTerm(subject));
for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(messages[i].getSubject() + "\t"
                    + messages[i].getSentDate());
}
```